# Let $ Y = \{ (1,1),(0,0\} \subset \mathbb A_k^2$. Find the $ \mathbb I(Y)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $ Y = \{ (1,1),(0,0\} \subset \mathbb A_k^2$. Find the $ \mathbb I(Y)$.

As if $f(x,y) \in \mathbb I(Y)$ then as $f(0,0)=0$ hence constant term of $f$ is zero and as $f(1,1)=0$ therefore sum of the coefficients of $f(x,y)$ is zero. But how can we describe this set properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $f\in (x,y)\cap (x-1,y-1)$. Now try to show this: $$(x,y)\cap (x-1,y-1)=(x-y,x(x-1),y(y-1)).$$

Furthermore, $$(x-y,x(x-1),y(y-1))=(x-y,x^2-y).$$

Comment: Thanks ! It's clear that RHS is contained in LHS but how to prove the reverse inequality?

Comment: @Learner Write $f=xf_1+yf_2=(x-1)g_1+(y-1)g_2$, notice that $g_1+g_2\in(x,y)$, write $g_1+g_2=xh_1+yh_2$, and then plugin $g_2$ into the first relation.

Comment: Sorry,why $g_1+g_2 \in (x,y)$ ?

Comment: @Learner $x(g_1-f_1)+y(g_2-f_2)=\ ?$

Comment: ohh I see,Thanks a lot!